# What is the best way to test multiple derived types using Xunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have an interface `IFoo`

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void DoSomeStuff();
}
```

And I have two derived types `FooImpl1` and `FooImpl2`:

```
public class FooImpl1 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class FooImpl2 : IFoo
{
    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        //Should do EXACTLY the same job as FooImpl1.DoSomeStuff()
    }
}
```

I have a test class which tests `IFoo` contract of `FooImpl1` :

```
    private static IFoo FooFactory()
    {
        return new FooImpl1();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void TestDoSomeStuff()
    {
        IFoo foo = FooFactory();

        //Assertions.
    }
```

How can I reuse this test class to test both `FooImpl1` and `FooImpl2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about having base class for `IFoo` tests with abstract method returning appropriate implementation?

```
public abstract class FooTestsBase
{
    protected abstract IFoo GetTestedInstance();

    [Fact]
    public void TestDoSomeStuff()
    {
        var testedInstance = GetTestedInstance();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, all derived types have to do is simply provide that one instance:

```
public class FooImpl1Tests : FooTestsBase
{
    protected override IFoo GetTestedInstance()
    {
        return new FooImpl1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work with `xunit 2` and `reshaper-xunit`? I get `Test from abstract fixture is not runnable itself` for the shared facts.